# How can I use Like with data that contains the # special character in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2016 and have a table of items where the user stores tags for each item as a string text separated by commas, with each tag prefaced by a `#` character. For example:

> ItemTag: *#Tools,#Perishable,#Kit,#Tool Kit,#Screws, #drill bit*

I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to select one or more tags from a multi select listbox and have the form display all item records where the `ItemTag` field contains the tag(s) the user selected. I'm trying to do this in VBA, but I seem to get caught up with the `#` character. I can create a query and use:

```
Like "*[#]drill bit*"
```

but this does not work in VBA. Here's the code I'm working with at present:

```vb
strsql = "SELECT * FROM [tmpTagSearch]"
With Me

  'Filter by Tags selected in the Tags multi-select listbox
      Dim varItm As Variant, strIN As String

      If .cmbTags.ItemsSelected.count > 0 Then
          For Each varItm In .cmbTags.ItemsSelected
              If strIN = "" Then
                  strIN = "'" & .cmbTags.Column(0, varItm) & "'"
              Else
                  strIN = strIN & ",'" & .cmbTags.Column(0, varItm) & "'"
              End If
              varItm = varItm + 1
          Next varItm

          If Len(strIN) > 0 And strIN <> "*" Then
              strsql = strsql & " WHERE (([InventoryTag]) IN (" & strIN & "))"
          Else
              strsql = strsql & ")"
          End If
      Else
         ' strsql = strsql & ")"
      End If

  Me.RecordSource = strsql

End With
```

Comment: Start by sharing the problematic SQL string that code generates, not the full code. That should be way easier to debug

Comment: In your code there is no **Like**.., What is the error massage?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single-quotes from the strIN and frame each item with double quotes.  This works >>

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE InventoryTag  In  ("#Tools",  "#Kit")
```